# Console using APIENTRY closes immediately

Tags: c, winapi

Visual studio does not show any error but when run with debug or without the console closes immediately. I used a while loop to prevent it from closing but printf string is not displayed.
Here is my code :

```
#include <Windows.h>

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    AllocConsole(); 
    HWND windowHandle = FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL);
    ShowWindow(windowHandle, 10);

    printf("Blehh");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: but what you really wait here ? you exit from *wWinMain* and *ExitProcess* called

Comment: On a side note, you can use [`GetConsoleWindow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolewindow) to get the HWND of the console associated with the calling process, you don't need to use `FindWindow()`, which may find the wrong window if there are multiple consoles active at a time.

Comment: Just need the console to remain open and display the printf string

Comment: @YashMalviya the problem is that the process terminates, destroying the console it created, once `wWinMain()` exits, so you need to block it from exiting, like paulsm4's answer shows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redirect the standard input and output to the created console, and flush the buffer after the output.

Here is the code :

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    AllocConsole();
    HWND windowHandle = FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL);
    ShowWindow(windowHandle, SW_NORMAL);
    FILE* fDummy;
    freopen_s(&fDummy, "CONIN$", "r", stdin);
    freopen_s(&fDummy, "CONOUT$", "w", stderr);
    freopen_s(&fDummy, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
    printf("Blehh");
    fflush(fDummy);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

And it works for me.

Answer (score 3):

Trying adding a "pause" before your "return 0"; e.g. `getchar();` or `system("pause");`

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    AllocConsole(); 
    HWND windowHandle = FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL);
    ShowWindow(windowHandle, 10);

    printf("Blehh");
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This does work but the printf string isnt displayed. Like i said i used while loop before to prevent it

Comment: @YashMalviya `printf()` is generally line-buffered. Try `printf("Blehh\n");`

Comment: @YashMalviya: 1) You've fixed the "disappearing window" ;) Good.  2) DaV is correct: C library functions use [buffered I/O](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/i-o-buffering-and-its-various-techniques).  One solution is to add "\n" (DOS carriage return/linefeed) to your printf string.  Another is to call [fflush()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fflush).  Please "upvote" and/or "accept" this response if you found it helpful.